# Random dice roll with 6 counters using arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, random

This excersise is a bit challenging. Beginner coder using Javascript console. I can't figure out how to print each number in it's own row.

**Question:**

Use variables, arrays and constants to show how random dice roll.
Define a loop that will call the random function 10000 times. Use 6 counters to show when each number appears. Display the die number and the number of times it appeared followed by a scaled histogram that shows 1 star for each 40 appearances.

**Output should look like this:**

```
1: (1587) 11111111111111111111111
2: (1542) 222222222222222
3: (1561) 333333333333333333333333
4: (1590) 44444444444444444444444
5: (1523) 555555555555555555
6: (1509) 66666666666666666666
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
var NUM_ROLLS = 10000;

function start(){
    var rolls = diceRoll();
    printArray(rolls);
}

//I divided NUM_ROLLS by 500 because I didn't want it to crush.//
//My output is not correct.//

function diceRoll(){
    var rolls = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < NUM_ROLLS/500; i++){
        if(Randomizer.nextBoolean()){
            rolls.push([1]);
            rolls.push([2]);
            rolls.push([3]);
            rolls.push([4]);
            rolls.push([5]);
            rolls.push([6]);
        
        }
    }
    return rolls;
}

function printArray(arr){
    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
        println(i + ": " + arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What output does your code give?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to store a count of each roll rather than pushing the roll itself to an array. Then to output the counts correctly, you can just divide the # of rolls by 40 and output that number that many times.

```js
var NUM_ROLLS = 10000;

function start() {
  var rolls = diceRoll();
  printArray(rolls);
}

function diceRoll() {
  //store the counts in an array
  var rolls = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < NUM_ROLLS; i++) {
    var result = parseInt(Math.random() * 6);
    rolls[result]++; //track the roll
  }
  return rolls;
}

function printArray(arr) {
  //output 1-6
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    //output the digit and count
    var line = (i + 1) + ": (" + arr[i] + ") ";
    //output a digit for every 40 rolls
    line += (i+1).toString().repeat(parseInt(arr[i] / 40));
    console.log(line);
  }
}

start();
```

Comment: Thanks, the output is pefect but, I can't use : toString(), parseInt, Math.random(), or console.log. It has to be more basic.

Comment: What do you mean by "more basic"? Using native JS methods is pretty darn basic - no external dependencies, easier to maintain than writing your own methods, etc. What is your `Randomizer` object? And you can replace `console.log` with your own print method if you want. This is just a simple functional example that can be modified to fit your specific needs. You can replace the `rolls` counters with arrays (like you have in your question), and then just do `rolls[1].length` to get the count.

Comment: Yeah I used "println"

Comment: That's not a native JS method, so you need to make sure that's defined elsewhere in order to use it. Otherwise you _could_ do `document.write(line+"<br>");` instead, though this is generally frowned upon as an output method. Additionally, you'll need to add details about your `Randomizer` if you have to use it and aren't allowed to use `Math.random()`... though this is becoming out-of-scope for a question on SO.com because these are supposed to be general solutions (native JS is a good thing!), not answers to a single specific homework problem.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I think what I got can will be of great use.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've done it:

```js
var numROLLS = 10000;
var array;
function diceRoll() {
    array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    for (i = 0; i < numROLLS; i++) {
        array[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)]++
    }
}
function printArray() {
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        console.log((i+1) + ": (" + array[i] + ") " + (i+1).toString().padEnd(array[i] / 40, (i+1).toString()));
    }
}
function start() {
    diceRoll();
    printArray();
}
start();
```